# Bypass/Avoiding obstacle when the angle between the vector velocity and detected point is 90

Tags: math, vector, rotation, point, angle

[image]

I have the detected point by the sensor, I have velocity vector, the sensor position, drone position, the distance between the sensor and the detected point.
I'm trying a couple of days without solution.
How can i bypass the obstacle in 90 degrees? to be parallel to the obstacle.

I tried to find the angle between the velocity and the detected point and rotate the vector velocity by this angle, didn't work. or the object point and detected point and multiply it by the magntitude of the velocity.

Please any solution!!

Answer (score 0):

1. **number of points**

   **You can not do this from single measurement!** You need to sample at least 3 points/distances along the way. Then convert them to global world coordinates (or any **common** reference frame) let call them `p0,p1,p2`.
2. **wall**

   First check if the 3 point are on the same line

   ```
   u = p1-p0
   v = p2-p1
   | u/|u| - v/|v| | <= zero_threshold
   ```

   If no then the  wall is not planar or you hit more than one obstacle. In any such case you can not infer anything from it so you should measure again or turn away for safety...
3. **angle**

   In case your drone is flying in the same altitude or with its constant change (trajectory is line) then we can assume this as **2D** case. (In **3D** you would also need altitude measurements ... and use **3D** normal of the wall so **#2** would look very different). So the angle between wall and velocity is computed:

   ```
   dangle = acos( dot_product((p2-p0),velocity_vector) / (|p2-p0|*|velocity_vector|) )
   ```

   The sign of `dangle` is determined from the distances

   ```
   if (d0>d1>d2) turn away
   if (d0<d1<d2) turn in
   if (d0~=d1~=d2) no turn as you are parallel
   ```

   without knowing your coordinate system properties is hard to tell more. But You can simply check if rotated velocity vector will result in `dangle` near zero. If not change the sign to minus.